# Using the Skellam distribution in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, scipy

The [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) is the probability distribution of the difference of two independent Poisson distributed variables. So Skellam is based on subtraction. I've never used it before.

Considering `X` and `Y` which are two results of two Poisson formulas, precisely `X=21.75%` and `Y=7.58%`, how to apply the Skellam distribution?

```
#Calculate Poisson
mu_X = 2.6
X = ((mu_X ** 3) * 2.7182818284 ** (-mu_X)) / 6 * 100
X = 21.75%

mu_Y = 0.5
Y = ((mu_Y ** 2) * 2.7182818284 ** (-mu_Y)) / 2 * 100
Y = 7.58
```

I had thought of a simple, but it seems too banal, simple and definitely not correct.

```
#Incorrect use of Skellam
Z = 21.75% - 7.58%
Z = 14.17%
```

How to properly use the Skellam distribution and use it with Python? I would like to use it with `numpy` or `scipy`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by Poisson formula? The Poisson distribution is probability distribution, so do those percentages refer to probability of the Possion-distributed variables to be in a given interval? As it stands the question is not very clear to me!

Comment: @DavideFiocco I have updated my question. See if it's clearer now, fellow Italian :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, you're calculating the probability of two Poisson variables with different mean values `mu_X` and `mu_Y` to assume two values, respectively 3 and 2. You could recalculate your probabilities with

```py
from scipy.stats import poisson

mu_X = 2.6
mu_Y = 0.5

# Calculate the Poisson PMF for k=3 with mean mu_X
prob_X = poisson.pmf(3, mu_X) # about 21%

# Calculate the Poisson PMF for k=2 with mean mu_Y
prob_Y = poisson.pmf(2, mu_Y) # about 7%
```

The Skellam distribution answers the following questions instead: "What's the probability for the *difference* of the two Poisson variables above to be equal to a given value"?

To calculate that in Python you would use

```py
from scipy.stats import skellam

# Create a Skellam distribution with the two mean values
dist = skellam(mu_X, mu_Y)

# Calculate the probability of getting 1, just as example
prob = dist.pmf(1) # trying 1 but one could try whatever integer value of the difference
```

in both cases, `.pmf` gives you what you are looking for, the probability (Poisson in the former case, Skellam in the latter) in correspondence of the given input value.

In the case of the Skellam distribution, you'd put in input the value of the difference that you would like to know the probability of.

Comment: Scrivo in inglese per i lettori futuri. Why the value 1 in dist.pmf(1)? In reference to your "What's the probability that the difference of the two Poisson variables above to be a given value (let's say 1)"?, why did you set 1 and not another number?

Comment: Was just an example, because you had set the variables to be equal to 3 and 2 :) it could be whatever integer value.

Comment: There's something that doesn't add up, sorry. dist.pmf(1) what is it for? How do I choose which number to insert into dist.pmf(?)? If I only need the difference between mu_X and mu_Y, then what is dist.pmf(1) for and how to choose the number? Thanks and sorry

Comment: As the two Poisson vars can take whatever positive integer value (actually, you calculated the probability for them to assume some values of your choice, namely 2 and 3, in your example), their _difference_ can take whatever integer value, with a given probability. Calling `pmf` tells you what the value of that probability is, as a function of the value. P.S. Note that you are not calculating the difference between `mu_X` and `mu_Y`: those are just two numbers `2.6` and `0.5`, not distributions!

Comment: Let's take an example. We consider prob_X as the probability of a team
to score 3 goals. We take prob_Y as the probability of a team making 2 goals. 
The result of your code, which is 0.22, would be the probability of the difference of the two Poisson variables. What is dist.pmf(1) instead? In terms of value in here, what is it for? Can you explain more about the use of the value in dist.pmf(1)? What is the value here for? Thank you

Comment: `dist.pmf(1)`, in your example, is the probability of the difference of the goals of first team minus those of the second team to be equal to 1.

Comment: Are there usually stable values used in dist.pmf(?)? In my case, I will always have to use Skellam for the difference between the probabilities of specific goals. In the example I used 3 goals and 2 goals, but it can also be other different goals. That said, what number do you recommend using in dist.pmf(?)? How do I choose which value to insert into dist.pmf(?)?

Comment: You would use the value you are interested in knowing the probability of, as in "What is the likelihood of the difference in goals between the first team and the second team to be 100?" to that question, you would answer with `dist.pmf(100)` :)

Comment: If i use 100, i get the result 1.5367662878361078e-118

Comment: Hehe yes, and indeed with your example, with a team that scores on average 2.5 goals, and another that on average scores 0.5 goals, the probability to observe a difference of 100 in the scores of (two) matches (they play independently) is veeeeeery low :D

Comment: So what value should I use (instead of 100) to avoid this? Did you advise me to use 100? I'm sorry I did not understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255853/discussion-between-davide-fiocco-and-nonsaprei).